# Using Compute Engine in Eclipse with GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-compute-engine

I'm planning on making an online game using GWT (HTLM5/JavaScript) and Google Compute Engine for server. I used to make a turn-based game using AppEngine (servlets) and that worked fine. Is there a way (plugins etc) I can develop a Compute Engine project within Eclipse? Or what would be the best work flow in this case. Cloud9 seems interesting but, I'm not sure how does it integrate with an GWT/Eclipse project....

My aim is to make developing and debugging client/server stuff as fluent as possible, so other ideas are welcome too :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [documentation page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse). Based on the info there, it seems to suit your needs.